# sharepoint 2010 contacts duplicates

Tags: 2010, list, duplicate, contacts

I have created a contacts list in SharePoint 2010 and need to be able to stop duplicate contact information from being added to this list. I am not finding an "out of the box" method is there some way that I can do this without having to do any programming or does someone know of a reliable third party tool?

Answer (score 0):

Create a ItemAdding event handler and then check if contact already exists or not if it is then use `properties.cancel=true;` which will stop contact from being added.

Useful links

[Creating a SharePoint Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407274%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[SPItemEventProperties, How to stop an item from being added](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.aspx)

[Most efficient C# SharePoint List iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236786/most-efficient-c-sharp-sharepoint-list-iteration)